# List index out of range error in my program

Tags: python, error-handling

```
def to_camel_case(text):
    arr = []
    if '-' in text:
        arr = text.split('-')
    elif '_' in text:
        arr = text.split('_')
    z = []
    z.append(arr[0])
    for i in range(1, len(arr)):
        arr1 = list(arr[i])
        arr1[0] = arr1[0].upper()
        arr1 = ''.join(arr1)
        z.append(arr1)
    str = ''.join(z)
    return str
```

In the above program is there any list index out of range error. 
Pycharm doesn't show any error. But another ide shows list index out of range error. Why?

Comment: if you pass string without `-` or ` _` then you will get that error

Answer (score 1):

**1) The answer**
In case you pass a string **without** `-` or `_` character in parameter of `to_camel_case`, you have a `List index out of range error` on instruction `z.append(arr[0])` just because `arr` is an empty list in this case.
In case you pass a string **with** `-` or `_` character in parameter of `to_camel_case`, you don't have any error because `arr` is not empty in this case.
This very likely explains why sometimes you observe the error, sometimes you don't.

**2) Proposal of update based on your code**
With minimum modifications compared to your code, I suggest you the following update :

```
def to_camel_case(text):
    if '-' in text:
        arr = text.split('-')
    elif '_' in text:
        arr = text.split('_')
    else:
        arr = text.split(' ')
    z = []
    for i in range(0, len(arr)):
        arr1 = list(arr[i])
        arr1[0] = arr1[0].upper()
        arr1 = ''.join(arr1)
        z.append(arr1)
    resultStr = ' '.join(z)
    return resultStr

# All 3 following instructions return the same string "Toto Is My Friend !"
print(to_camel_case("toto is my friend !"))
print(to_camel_case("toto-is-my-friend !"))
print(to_camel_case("toto_is_my_friend !"))
```

**2) Going further**
You may consider the method `title()` applicable on `string` objects, that seems to do exactly what you want.